# macvim rails.vim hangs while running spec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vim, ruby-on-rails-3, macvim

I'm using the latest versions of MacVim, rails.vim and my terminal is ZSH. When I run a rspec (rspec2),the spec output buffer prints the output to a certain extent(around 10 lines) and then hangs, making the whole macvim hang. Then, when I press Ctrl+C, I see the remaining spec results (small no. of lines, all passed) with the 
'Press Enter or type command to continue.". While all this happens, the CPU usage for the 'VIM' process spikes up. I've also tried this with moving all the rc files out of the way. Also this problem might be specific to rspec2, since my older rspec projects work just fine.

I'm not exactly sure what the problem is here.

Answer (score 0):

Update to the latest snapshot - it fixes more than one type of freezing problems:

https://github.com/b4winckler/macvim/wiki/ChangeLog

Comment: This problem was reported on Snapshot 55 which is the latest at the moment